# Should the client upload files to my nodejs server with http post or socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there performance differences if I would send a file's data binary with socket.io?

Comment: File upload is probably optimized more via http post by the browser and the server, but you'd have to run a test to see what differences you could measure).

Comment: I will try it as soon as with large files and require("fs").watch  ~

Comment: A lot of people use [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for node.js file uploads.

Comment: with http-post: it takes 7-20ms(many tests) to upload a small file....the same for socket.io:it took 7-15ms(many test):  I get some ns_error_out_of_memory problems if I use large files,...I will try to develop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I developed now my test! And to sum up `HTTP.POST` is a way faster!

[image: socket]
above I used `Socket.IO` to upload an about `726mb file (express)`
[image: http]
above Here I used `http.post` together with `formidable` (without express)
There is one problem, with the `socket.io` way I had to send binary data which I read from the `(video.mov)726mb` file step by step, `(64*1024 Bytes reading and sending reading sending...to prevent some Memory Error).`

Maybe it would be a good idea to show you guys my code:

`Socket.IO Upload`:
[index.html](https://pastebin.com/Dsan2L3E)
[server.js](https://pastebin.com/7hcnyKLa)
`HTTP-POST Upload:(It's not my coding!):`
[server.js](https://pastebin.com/SF9rgVnM)

Answer (score -3):

Most browser will crash after uploading a file through HTTP during more than 2 minutes, so I would recommend using socket.io to upload big files. It also allows you to stop and restart uploads where you stopped them.

Comment: This is simply just not true.  Large uploads via http are fully supported, even if they take more than 2 minutes.

Comment: I made a website that allows you to publish videos with NodeJS one month ago and the connection crashed with standard HTTP GET requests, I had to use socket.io to make it work

Comment: Then you weren't doing something correctly.  This is not a fundamental limitation of browser HTTP uploads.

Comment: You shouldn't upload large files through `GET`, you should be using `POST` instead.

Comment: " It also allows you to stop and restart uploads where you stopped them " I think this is a really good advantage for using Socket.IO